# c# Generic on variable declaration, is this possible?

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following problem:

```cs
public class MyClass<T> where T : class
{
    private MyOtherClass<T, U> variable where U : class;
    ... content ...
}
public class MyOtherClass<T, U> where T : class where U : class
{
    ... content ...
}
```

Is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make the type of a field or property of `MyClass` generic based on some type parameter `U`, you have to declare that as a type parameter of `MyClass`:

```
public class MyClass<T, U> 
    where T : class 
    where U : class
{
    private MyOtherClass<T, U> variable;
    ... content ...
}
public class MyOtherClass<T, U>
    where T : class 
    where U : class
{
    ... content ...
}
```

However, that doesn't apply to methods. This is perfectly fine:

```
public class MyClass<T> 
    where T : class 
{
    private MyOtherClass<T, U> Method<U>() where U : class
    {
        ... content ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer the question as it is titled, you can't do that because`variable` is a *field* of type `MyOtherClass<T, U>`, which means `MyOtherClass` *defines* type parameters `T` and `U` - as you have it!

The `T` of `MyClass<T>` is not the same `T` as that of `MyOtherClass<T, U>`, because the *declaration* of generic type constraints *belongs* to the generic type itself, not to the types that use it - and that's good!

If it were possible, a type such as this:

```
public class SomeRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : IEntity { /* ... */}
```

Could possibly be used like this:

```
public class SomeService
{
    private SomeRepository<TEntity> _someRepo where TEntity : INotAnEntity
}
```

Interfaces, classes and methods can be generic (i.e. are able to define type constraints); fields and properties can't, but they can be of a generic type.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want `MyClass<T>` to contain a reference to `MyOtherClass<T, U>` where both `T`s match but any `U` is accepted. If this is what you're trying to do, the existing answers probably don't help because a method with a generic `U` parameter still requires the user to specify `U`.

Classes with type parameters (especially multiple ones) should inherit / implement something *less* generic to support situations like this. For example:

```
public interface IOtherThing<T> {
    T Value1 { get; }
    object Value2 { get; }
}

public class MyOtherClass<T, U> : IOtherThing<T> {
    public T Value1 { get { ... } }
    public U Value2 { get { ... } }
    object IOtherThing<T>.Value2 { get { return Value2; } }
}
```

Now, `MyClass<T>` can declare a variable as `IOtherThing<T>`, which can be assigned to any `MyOtherClass<T, U>`.

Comment: +1 Hadn't seen the question that way. If that's what the OP meant, good guess, and nice answer! By inheriting `MyOtherClass`, the `T` takes the same meaning in both types (they even need to have the same type constraints to compile).